# To format/reinstall XP, which network settings do I need to port to the new installation to ensure proper credentials?

Tags: windows-xp, networking, installation

I want to format my computer at work, but I need to make sure that the new installation of XP properly accesses my company's network. I would have IT do this, but we're a small outfit and don't have an IT department.

Obviously I have my login credentials, but are there specific Windows services or other tweaks I would need in place? I am assuming I can just copy down all of the settings as they are now before formatting, then just add those to the new installation, however I don't know which settings are important to transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on a Windows domain, you will almost certainly need to get the server/domain administrator involved, since only a user with domain administration permissions will be able to re-add your computer to the domain.

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to tell the answser to your question, since we don't know how your work network is set up.  Generally you just need your account and password.

Comment: Well I guess that's the heart of my question - is there any way to derive any additional settings from my current setup to ensure a smooth installation/connection with the network?